# Redirect user to same page on login

Tags: 7, users, redirection, authentication-authorization

I know there are a couple modules other there that handle login redirects like [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination), [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), [Login Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_redirect) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).  However, they all seem to only allow strict URLs.  I would like users to be redirected to the same page they logged in on.  The default behaviour of Drupal appears to redirect users to the previous page on login.

Since I am using a login modal, redirecting people to the previous page doesn't work well.

How can I redirect users to their current page when using a login modal that handles the login through AJAX?  I would appreciate a solution that could be placed in template.php maybe using [hook_user_login()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7)

Comment: Is algorithm enough?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the implementation in [`user_login_block()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_block/7), particularly this line:

```
$form['#action'] = url(current_path(), array('query' => drupal_get_destination(), 'external' => FALSE));
```

This will add the `destination` parameter to the URL, which takes precedence over any other arguments passed to [`drupal_goto()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) (like `$form_state['redirect']`).
Depending on how you create your modal, the easiest way would therefore be to simply append the `destination` argument for the current page to the form action.

Comment: My current user_login_block() looks like this:   $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => '_bootstrap_login_modal_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'ajax-' . $html_id . '-wrapper',
    'event' => 'click',
  );